# FFMPEG frame extraction - stuck

Tags: ffmpeg

trying to extract specific frames from a video with the following command (with specific names of files removed!:

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "select-gte(n\,6956)" -vframes 10262 folder/frame%d.jpg

However, in many cases, this results in the same frame (the first one) extracted repeatedly, rather than a progression of frames extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The image sequence muxer, by default, is set to assume a constant frame rate output, so it will fill in missing timestamp gaps with duplicates.

The select filter does not reset timestamps, so, in your command, there's a "gap" from 0 to the timestamp of the first selected frame.

Use instead

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "select-gte(n\,6956)" -vsync 0 -vframes 10262 folder/frame%d.jpg
```

This changes video sync method to prevent frame duplication.