# Extra frames when splitting video into frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to split a video into frames stored as `.jpg`. My video is `72.3` seconds long, has an average framerate of `2310/241` and has `693` frames as per output of the

```
ffprobe -i video.mp4 -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams
```

command. However, when I run the following command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 2310/241 frames_fixed_rate/frame_%5d.jpg
```

I get `695` images instead of the expected `693`. What can be the cause of this?

Here's the output of the `ffmpeg` command

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.37.101
  Duration: 00:01:12.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 436 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 3825:3824 DAR 425:239], 400 kb/s, 9.59 fps, 10 tbr, 90k tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1065c6000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'frames_fixed_rate/frame_%5d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x360 [SAR 3825:3824 DAR 425:239], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 9.59 fps, 9.59 tbn, 9.59 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  695 fps=0.0 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:12.50 bitrate=N/A dup=27 drop=25 speed=82.1x    
video:5287kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Same reason as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496885

Comment: As I understand, in the question you linked, the solution was to add the `-vsync 0` option. When I try adding this option to my `ffmpeg` command, it warns me that `Using -vsync 0 and -r can produce invalid output files` and fails with the following error message: `[mjpeg @ 0x7f9faa00de00] Invalid pts (12) <= last (12)` after producing 13 frames. Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but when I try passing a fixed number of frames as in `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -frames:v 693 frames_fixed_count/frame_%5d.jpg`. I get the expected 693 frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image muxer in ffmpeg defaults to constant frame rate output, so if the input is 30 fps but there are portions with fewer or greater than 30 frames per second, then ffmpeg will, by default, duplicate or drop frames respectively, so that a constant rate of 30 fps in the output is maintained.

To override this behaviour, add `-vsync 0`. Additionally, some encoders, like JPEG, will complain if two or more frames have the same output timestamp. This can happen when the old timestamp, denominated in terms of the input stream timebase is finer than the output stream timebase. For this, we will retime frames to avoid duplicate timestamps. When we do the latter, vsync can be omitted.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf setpts=N/TB -r 1 frames_fixed_rate/frame_%5d.jpg
```